# Wifi hotspot with Broadcom BCM43227 Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, network-manager, broadcom

I'm trying to configure a WiFi hotspot on my desktop with a BCM43227 WiFi card.

I've tried the hostapd method but I fail with this message :

```
nl80211: Failed to set channel (freq=2432): -22 (Invalid argument)
```

Nevertheless, I've succeeded with `nmcli`.

So my new problem is: How to personalize DHCP (Choose the spool of addresses) and how to personalize DNS (define local area names) by using the `nmcli` AP creation method.

Can someone help me ?
(I take solution with hostapd too ! )

Answer (score 0):

I bought a wireless card with the Broadcam chip, and as a result, after searching on the net for so long, i found out that broadcam doesn't support hospot or being an AP. Even tho it said that it worked on ur screen, i think when u'll proceed to other stuff, u'll have issues. Thats what I know so if but if ur case is different, someone may help u. And if u found out that ur wireless card doesnt support the hotspot thing, then i recommend u to buy a Tp link wireless card with atheros chip. Thanks for ur attention.

Comment: Hi,Thanks for your messages. According iwlist the AP mode is supported by the BCM43227 and the AP is well with nmcli.